# Change EditorConfig to flag certain exceptions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, editorconfig

Is there a way to cause using a certain type of `Exception` to show as an error (or warning, or info) for .NET projects in Visual Studio?

I was thinking changing the [.editorconfig file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019) would do the trick, but even with [the options available for code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview) I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Exceptions are unexpected States. If you expect a specfic state, check for it. If it isn't true, show a warning or an Info. Use exceptions only if something unexpected is happen.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt the question is concerning when exceptions are present in the code, such as when the words `throw new NotImplementedException();` are literally in a .cs file. This has nothing to do with runtime state.

Comment: Well, if it's a custom exception, you could trigger a warning by using the `ObsoleteAttribute` , an Error by commenting it out. That being said, I think you are looking for an [RoslynAnalyzer](https://joshvarty.com/learn-roslyn-now/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a task for editorConfig alone, but requires StyleCop to be enabled as well. Rule [CA1031](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1031) is designed for this task.

You can set in your `.editorConfig`:

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA1031.disallowed_symbol_names = NullReferenceException
```

(If you don't want that people catch `NullReferenceException` anywhere)

StyleCop is enabled on .NET 5.0 projects by default, for older projects, it must be enabled by including the appropriate nuget package.